# Getting error while trying to run API with flask_restful

Tags: python, flask

I currently have an API that looks like this (for testing):

```
from flask_restful import Resource, request


class UploadFile(Resource):

    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        is_header_present(request.headers, "User-Agent", None)


def is_header_present(headers, search_term, correct_variable):
    for header in headers.keys():
        print(header)
```

While running this API using the following code:

```
    from flask import Flask
    from flask_restful import Api
    from lib.api import UploadFile

    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)
    api.add_resource(UploadFile, "/cas", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    app.run(
        host="127.0.0.1", port=6823
    )
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cas.py", line 262, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/home/sal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/home/sal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .serving import run_simple
  File "/home/sal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 50, in <module>
    from ._internal import _log
  File "/home/sal/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/_internal.py", line 11, in <module>
    import inspect
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py", line 36, in <module>
    import dis
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/dis.py", line 9, in <module>
    from opcode import __all__ as _opcodes_all
ImportError: cannot import name '__all__'
```

My current installation versions of Flask, flask_restful, and Werkzeug are as follows:

- Flask==2.0.3
- Flask-RESTful==0.3.9
- Werkzeug==2.0.3

I have never encountered this error before so I'm not sure what to do, and it seems that Googling the error produces no results for the issue. How can I fix this error and continue?

My python version is: 3.6.9

I tried reinstalling the libraries, I tried Googling for a fix, I also tried reinstalling python.

Answer (score 0):

I had a file called `opcode.py` inside of my base directory so it was trying to load that file instead of the original. Deleting that file worked.